# Two lines images with x-overflow:scroll

Tags: css

I have a block with two lines images. Each image is inline-block. I need fixed size width and height for container and when images will be 12 or more we should see x-scrollbar not y and and all overflow images should go to the right side not to bottom. For now all pictures go down to third line.

My container css:

```
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
  height: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
```

My images in container:

```
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 17px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 7px 17px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 17px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

Please see example here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6E5b.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `overflow-x: scrollbar;` ? perhaps you mean `overflow-x: scroll;`

Comment: Yes, sorry for this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by javaScript. Just find middle element in awards and append after it break line.

```
var numberAwards = $('.b-awards .e-award').length;
$('.b-awards .e-award').eq(numberAwards/2-1).after( "<div class='e-award__break-line' style=\"content: '\\A' \"></div>" );
```